# format javascript date and add 365 days

Tags: javascript, date

I want to add 365 days to a formatted javascript date.

```
var today = new Date();
var day = today.getDate();
var month = today.getMonth();
var year = today.getFullYear();
today = year +"-"+ day +"-"+ month;
var duedate = new Date(today);
duedate.setDate(today.getDate() + 365);
```

Console says that today.getDate() in the last line is not a function. How do I correctly add 365 days to the formatted date? Thank you!

Comment: `today` is a string, so the error is right, there is no method `String.prototype.getDate` (see line: `today = year +"-"+ day +"-"+ month;`).

Comment: Do not use the Date constructor to parse strings, it's unreliable even if it does "work" in some browsers some of the time. The format you are providing (y-d-m) will most likely be interpreted as y-m-d or invalid. To copy a date, use: `var dateCopy = new Date(+date);` where *date* is a date object.

Comment: What format is the input string? Parsing date strings is pretty simple, so is formatting them but you need to show what the format is.

Answer (score 3):

With a Date object you can do that.

```js
var now = new Date();
var duedate = new Date(now);
duedate.setDate(now.getDate() + 365);
console.log("Now:     ", now);
console.log("Due Date:", duedate);
```

Is it necessary to edit formatted date? In that case you would need to operate with strings/substrings. Not very beautiful approach.

Comment: Yes, it is necessary. I did this in jsfiddle. It seems to work. http://jsfiddle.net/2jmLfe0s/

Comment: @propernoun—"seems to work" is pretty vague, if you look at the values being generated, it's not doing what you think.

Comment: I don't see how it isn't. It is adding a year to the date and then comparing the two dates.

Comment: I looked again at what I did and reworked it to this. Would you mind telling me if I hit closer to the target this time? http://jsfiddle.net/02c8z33s/

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is to remove

```
today = year +"-"+ day +"-"+ month;
```

This line converts the date object into string.

Comment: I need the date to be formatted this way. I figured out what to do though. Thanks.